# pysmb not working on linux ubuntu server 22.04 LTS

Tags: python-3.x, linux, smb, pysmb

I have a telegram bot and there I implemented support for receiving files from a file server, in my case smb. The problem is that on the local everything works fine! You also need to keep in mind that I have Ubuntu 20.04 on my local. This is the only thing I haven't been able to check. And I checked the following points.

- on the server, the python version was 3.10.4, on the local 3.9. Then i installed the latest version of python and the project works great!
- and on the server, when trying to make a connection to SMB, there was an error:

  ```
    File "bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/smb/utils/md4.py", line 251, in int_array2str
    nstr = nstr + str(chr(i))
    TypeError: 'U32' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
  ```

Then I found this problem on the [Python discuss](https://discuss.python.org/t/python-3-10-4-smb-package-md4-bug/16015) and tried to do the same. This error disappeared but another, more direct one came up. Now it's just AssertionError and points to the string with the connection attempt.

This is my code with connection:

```
conn = SMBConnection(
    SMB_LOGIN, SMB_PASSWORD,
    LOCAL_NAME, SMB_REMOTE_NAME, use_ntlm_v2=True
)
assert conn.connect(SMB_IP_ADDRESS, 139)
```

There doesn't seem to be anything remarkable here.
I also tried to change ports, put 445/135/137.

445:

```
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

135 and 137:
timeout expired

A simple connection via the smbclient from the terminal also works.
I don't understand what exactly is the problem. The only thing left for me to check is to change the version of Linux. But I also do not believe that after that it will start working

Comment: for reference file server windows 2016

Comment: Hi Abduhamidov Jordan - Were you able to figure out what could be issue? I am also facing same issue in the new linux server

Comment: Hello, kalaiyarasi Uma ! Yes, i find solution for this problem. 
Firstly, I created a try block for different ports 139 and 445, then manually entered the IP address in the field as a string. I'm also gave instructions to sys. admins should double-check account permissions. P.S. works in Python version 3.10.12 and pysmb=1.2.7